# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'url' when using feedparser in Django

Tags: django, feedparser

This is follow up to the question from here [bozo_exception in Django / feedparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071602/bozo-exception-in-django-feedparser)

I would like to iterate through many feeds from models/DB and have each of them displayed in the html template. While I do understand that I need to iterate thought x.feed.entries in the html template, I assume that iteration through each rss source needs to happen in the view function correct?

```
def feed5(request):
    source = Feed.objects.all()
    for item in source.url:
        rss = feedparser.parse(item)
    context = {'rss': rss,}
    return render(request, 'feedreader/feed5.html', context)
```

gives me this error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'url'. Not sure how should I go about it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it actually doesn't - Python isn't lying to you. See, `source` is a `QuerySet`, a list-like structure of results, not a single result. If it's your `Feed` model that should have a url attribute, then look it up on it and not the query set:

```
for item in source:
    rss = feedparser.parse(item.url)
```

Comment: OK, so now I have this in #views
`def feed5(request):
    source = Feed.objects.all()
    for item in source:
        rss = feedparser.parse(item.url)
    context = {'rss': rss}
    return render(request, 'feedreader/feed5.html', context)`

##feed5.html looks like this 
`<p><a href ="{{ rss.feed.link }}">{{ rss.feed.title }}</a></p>
<ul>
{% for r in rss.entries|slice:":15" %}
<li> <a class="title" href="{{ r.link }}">{{ r.title }}</a> <br />{{ r.description|striptags }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
`
but the page displays rss entries only from one source and ignores skips all others from DB. Why?

Comment: You're only passing the last item into the context, as it is the last assignment. It doesn't matter that you iterate over everything. Instead, build up the data in some list (`li.append(rss)`) in the loop), pass the whole list in the context and iterate over the items of all of the feeds in your template (you'll need nested for-s).

Comment: Got it, thanks!

`def feed5(request):
    source = Feed.objects.all()
    list = []
    for item in source:
        rss = feedparser.parse(item.url)
        list.append(rss)
    context = {'rss': list}
    return render(request, 'feedreader/feed5.html', context)`